# I can't control font size within caption

Tags: fonts, captions

Here's my preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcommand{\vs}{\vspace{.1in}}
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\figc}[1]{Fig. II.~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig. II..}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{67}
\begin{document}
```

and my figure insert

```
\begin{figure}[h]
     \centering
     \includegraphics[height=40mm]{IMAGES/xxx.jpg}
     \caption {\small{ my caption text}}\label{II068}
\end{figure}
```

Despite the `\small`, caption prints same size as rest of text.

Comment: it should work (although you have the wrong syntax, `\small` does not take an argument, so `\small my caption` not `\small{ my caption}`) however you should not hav font changes here, you want to separate such formating to document level settings so all captions are consisent, and the same text can use different sizes in the caption and in the list of figures.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\usepackage[font=small]{caption}` on line 3 to set the font size instead of doing it in `\caption` command.
This is detailed in page 10 of [`caption` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf).

[image: Screenshot from the package manual]

Comment: Great advice! I was not aware of the LaTeX package "caption". Thanks.