# How do I change the caption of the figure to "graph"?

Tags: captions

Currently my code is

`\caption{Change in biomass in KCl group}`

and it displays "figure 1: Change in biomass in KCl group"

however I would like to change it to

"Graph 1: Change in biomass in KCl group"

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please note that the site guidelines strongly recommend holding off for several hours, and maybe even a day or two, before "accepting" an answer. It is, of course, ok to upvote answers immediately if they meet your typesetting needs. But by accepting the very first answer that's provide within minutes of it being posted, you essentially discourage others from providing alternative -- and possibly better -- answers.

Comment: @Mico thanks for writing that, I have been on this site for around 8 months and that's the first time I have heard we should be doing that. I will take that into account with future questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `caption` package is not compatible with all LaTeX document classes. For extra robustness, I would simply modify the low-level macro `\figurename` directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or any other suitable document class
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Graph}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht] \caption{Change in biomass in KCl group} \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mico

Answer (score 11):

Another solution would be to define a new float environment with the `float`  package, thus having the possibility to have distinct lists of figures and of graphs:

```
    \documentclass{article} % or any other suitable document class
    \usepackage{float}

    \newfloat{Graph}{htbp}{grf}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{Graph}[ht]
    \centering
    Fiddle Dee Dee!
     \caption{Change in biomass in KCl group} \end{Graph}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use the `caption` package to change the name.

```tex
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name={Graph}}
```

This is explained on page 15 of [`caption` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf).
This is actually connected to my [recent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/637618/234654).

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

### EDIT

Consider the following MWE.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name={Graph}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... where in the code does the captionsetup go?

Comment: That should be put in the preamble. I have edited to add a minimum working example (MWE).

Comment: Now it works perfectly! Thanks Jerry. Turns out I used both Caption2 and Caption in the preamble...Silly mistake.

Comment: If you recommend using the `caption` package and its `name=...` option, you should also give a heads up about other, possibly unwanted, side-effects that result from using the `caption` package. For instance, the default spacing between the caption changes by loading the `caption` package.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! Now I know a better understanding of it.

Comment: sorry guys I ran into another problem... How do I keep some of the figures captions as the original "figure 1" and only modify the wanted ones to "graph 1"?

Comment: Solution for my answer: put the setup in the figure (`\captionsetup{name=graph}`); for Mico's answer, also put renewcommand inside the figure.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again.